# How can I get a deeper / lower level insight into how my transaction is processed with sidecar?

Tags: extrinsic, block, transactions, sidecar

How can I see in more detail what operations are executed when my transaction is submitted ?

If there is a way to see all operations/extrinsics/calls that happened in a specific block then that could be useful also.

My goal is to get a more low level insight into the transaction process / block by using sidecar.

Answer (score 6):

Sidecar provides the following experimental `trace` related endpoints :

```
/experimental/blocks/{blockId}/traces/operations?actions=false
/experimental/blocks/head/traces/operations?actions=false
/experimental/blocks/{blockId}/traces
/experimental/blocks/head/traces
```

These endpoints were introduced & described in more detail in this [PR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/pull/383)

And the result from these endpoints is very well explained in this [diagram](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1vZoJo9jaXlz0LmrdTOgHck9_1LsfuQPRmTr-5g1tOis/edit)

To be able to get these endpoints you need to check 2 things :

1. Run your node with the flag `—unsafe-rpc-external`
2. Check that the `BlocksTrace` controller has been activated for the chain you are running.

More details on that you can find in this closed [issue](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/issues/866)

Right now, since these endpoints are experimental there are available by default only for Kusama and Polkadot running nodes (by using the flag mentioned above).

For other chains, the `BlocksTrace` controller is not active by default so you have to do it manually so add the `BlocksTrace` controller locally in the corresponding controller file of your chain, eg. for Polkadot is this [file](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/blob/master/src/chains-config/polkadotControllers.ts)